# c# datagridview datasource after update not showing new row

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource

Updating the DataGridView DataSource (List) from my API json data, the values is updated on the grid, but the new row is not added, i need to change order to see the newly added row.

I have custom function to order the datagridview datasource (List), i created the reset option and if i use it it's working, but i don't know why.

```
        if (OrderElement == "Seller")
        {
            if (Seller_SortType == false)
            {
                List = List.OrderBy(o => o.Seller).ToList();
                Seller_SortType = true;
            }
            else
            {
                List = List.OrderByDescending(o => o.Seller).ToList();
                Seller_SortType = false;
            }
        }
        else if (OrderElement == "Reset")
        {
            List = List.ToList();
        }

        // This function updating my datagridview datasource dgv.DataSource = List;
        MainAddTable();
```

Tried to add dgv.Update(); and dgv.Refresh(); after the dgv datasource is updated, but it's not working.

Comment: `dgv.DataSource = null; dgv.DataSource = List;`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov it's not good practice to null the datasource because the existing columns is detroyed.